# Is node.js more suited for NoSQL database compared to relational database given that node.js is usually associated with NoSQL database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, relational-database, nosql

Node.js projects are usually associated with NoSQL databases like MongoDB. Seldom do I encounter node.js projects with relational databases like MySQL. Are there engineering reasons why node.js is more suited for NoSQL databases?

Comment: *"Node.js projects are usually associated with NoSQL databases like MongoDB"* - [{{citation needed}}](https://xkcd.com/285/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is not more suited for NoSql vs Sql. There is modules available to interface with both equally. The main reason I can see for using a NoSql database such as mongoose is to have a fully javascript / json stack. Mongoose documents are essentially javascript objects, which makes for a consistent and simple stack.